# Play .wav when text scrolls in terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, audio

After watching a TV show, I came up with a fun idea. Is there a way to take that cheesy high-pitched sound effect they play every time text scrolls down a command-line screen on TV and play it when text scrolls in my terminal window (talking X here)?  Bonus points if you can modulate it with the amount/speed of scrolling text.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point: `command | tee >(aplay -r 32000 2> /dev/null &); pkill aplay`
Try it with `dmesg` or `ls -l /usr/bin` to test. (Set your volume low first)

Tee simply splits output to two places.  There is a pkill aplay so that the sound ends when the command exits. Adjust the rate (-r 32000) to make it higher or lower.  Note that this is very annoying and loud with the current settings.  Aplay also doesn't like it when its input is too short (25 characters was the minimum for me, but I don't know enough about aplay to say for certain).

It would need heavy tweaking and regulation to be comfortably usable on a permanent basis.  If you make any improvements, please share them.